# To council someone?

Tags: grammar

I'm reading a book called "The Immortals of Meluha", wherein a character asks another character: "Why will you not council me?"

Is this a typo? Or am I wrong in that the only appropriate word here is counsel and not council?

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/counsel_1

Answer (score 5):

There is not a [dictionary definition for council as a verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/council) - it seems most likely to be a typo.

However, English is fairly liberal about appropriating nouns as verbs, I am not familiar with the specific source you reference, and sometimes fiction likes to make up words or use them incorrectly on purpose to create a world, as satirized by [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/483/).

I could see "council" being used as a short hand for "appointing to a council" or something similar, though unlikely to ever be used to mean a synonym of counsel except in error, and would not be understood as anything but an error without proper context.

Given the word "[counsel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counsel)" fits perfectly in the situation you give, an error is most likely.